# Selecting all the Magasin(stores) with at least 1 product in it with also a qte_stock>0 SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE DATABASE Gestion_Magasin
GO

USE Gestion_Magasin
GO

CREATE TABLE Magasin
(
    NUM_MAG int PRIMARY KEY,
    NOM_MAG varchar(15),
    SUPERFICIE int CHECK (SUPERFICIE BETWEEN -1 AND 120),
    REF_PRODUIT int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PRODUIT(REF_PRODUIT)
)

CREATE TABLE PRODUIT
(
    REF_PRODUIT int PRIMARY KEY,
    DESIGNATION varchar(25),
    QTE_STOCK int DEFAULT 0,
)

SELECT * FROM Magasin
SELECT * FROM PRODUIT
```

### Heading

//This is the view where I m facing this problem ty for your help .

```
CREATE VIEW vue01
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM magasin AS m  
    JOIN PRODUIT AS p ON m.REF_PRODUIT = p.REF_PRODUIT 
    WHERE COUNT(m.REF_Produit) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put it like this without doing an aggregate
Use having instead

```
SELECT p.REF_PRODUIT, NUM_MAG, NOM_MAG,SUPERFICIE 
FROM magasin AS m  
JOIN PRODUIT AS p ON m.REF_PRODUIT = p.REF_PRODUIT 
group by p.REF_PRODUIT, NUM_MAG, NOM_MAG,SUPERFICIE 
having COUNT(m.REF_Produit) > 0
```